# how to read arduino board info serial no programmatically

Tags: arduino-uno

well I am try to make an project with original arduino. but I want to make this project unique. if my codes are copied and loaded another arduino board, my app should not work. how can make unique app, are there any idea? on Arduino IDE Tools> Get Board İnfo> SN look unique id. but how can read it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The serial number is burned into the ATMega16U2 chip and is only available to the computer over the USB interface.  There is no method for you to get it from the UART interface that connects the two MCUs together.

To stop people copying your code there are two things you need to do:

1. Don't allow anyone access to the source code or any compiled code files, and
2. Enable the "code protection" facility of the ATMega328P.

The latter will stop people being able to read the code from the Arduino. It would also be beneficial to remove the bootloader and program the board directly. That way there is no other possible route for getting at your code.

You enable code protection by setting the correct fuse bits.